# Are the higher direct images of pluricanonical bundles torsion-free?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry

Suppose $f: X\rightarrow S$ is a projective smooth morphism to a smooth variety $S$. Let $m\geq 2$ be a natural number.
It is known that the first higher direct image sheaf $R^1f_*\mathcal{O}_X(mK_X)$ is torsion-free according to Siu's invariance of plurigenera.

My question is, are the higher direct image sheaves $R^if_*\mathcal{O}_X(mK_X),i\geq 2$ also torsion-free?

Comment: Consider a family of blowups of the plane at $9$ points that specialize from general position to $9$ collinear points.

Comment: Even better: use $10$ points specializing from general position to $10$ collinear points.   Let $m$ equal $2$.